# Getting Specific text out of logs

Tags: text-processing, logs

I have log files like this for some top data:

```
Mon May  9 23:45:02 EDT 2016
PID   USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
14816 radius    25   0  848m 415m  10m S   10  2.6 274:05.28 java
```

How does one get the first line and just the value for %MEM?

I have tried `sed`/`awk`/`paste` but not having any luck.

Somehow the data is not perfect in that I can't always trust the the value is the 21st spot.

Comment: what don't you trust about the 21st column? It looks to me like %MEM would be the 10th column, but are there lines where previous fields have spaces, throwing off the column alignment? Maybe there's another way to solve your problem, or are you set on post-processing `top` output?

Comment: I was using paste to make the first 3 lines of each file one big line and then am trying to get the 21st field as well as others. I think you're right the column alignment somehow might be off but I can't see the issue if I look at the source data (there are many source files). It 'looks' OK. My goal is to put all of the extracted into one big file.

Comment: Edit your post and add the desired output... You want it in one line for each log file, right ?

Comment: @jouell: still confused, if you want the memory percentage from concatenated lines the field would be 28?

Comment: @tink - you're right. I also ran into another problem, I had 2 different formats to contend with, so one column was 21 and the other 28. In the end this worked out using paste -d@ - - -  to concatenate the first 3 lines and  tr -s ' ' and the cutting and awking. I still really don't know why but I had extra spaces in the file so the tr slurped up the extra whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

An awk moment:

```
$ awk 'NR == 1 {print;} NR == 2 {print $10; exit;}' input
```

Comment: Try NR == 3, maybe? I don't think he wanted the static string %MEM to show up ....

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `head`/`tail` and `awk` :

```
head -1 logfile 
tail -n +2 logfile | awk '{print $10}'
```